# Unit Testing VueRouter with the :to Attribute

Tags: jestjs, vue-router, vue-test-utils

I have a simple test case (Vue 2, Vuetify 2, vue-router, jest, vue-test-utils) where a Vuetify v-btn component is clicked and goes to a new route

```
<v-btn id="create-plan-btn" :to="{ 'name': 'newPlan', query: { dept: 216001 }}">Create plan</v-btn>
```

However, I am unable to figure out how to register a click method that captures the **:to** property's action.

```
describe('when "Create Plan button is clicked', () => {
  const localVue = createLocalVue()
  let vuetify

  beforeEach(() => {
    vuetify = new Vuetify()
  })

  const $route = { path: '/student/index', name: 'studentLanding' }

  const mockRouter = {
    to: jest.fn(),
    push: jest.fn()
  }
  const wrapper = shallowMount(StudentLanding, {
    localVue,
    stubs: {'router-link': RouterLinkStub},
    mocks: {
      $route: $route,
      $router: mockRouter
    }
  })

  it('triggers Vue router call to the new plan page', async () => {
    const button = wrapper.find('#create-plan-btn')
    expect(button.exists()).toBe(true)
    expect(mockRouter.push).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(0)
    button.vm.$emit('click') // Vuetify buttons need "vm.$emit" to be triggered, not "trigger()" like a normal HTML button would
    await wrapper.vm.$nextTick()
    expect(mockRouter.push).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
    expect(mockRouter.push).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ name: 'newPlan', query: { dept: 216001 }})
  })
})
```

> ● when "Create Plan button is clicked › triggers Vue router call to
> the new plan page
>
> ```
> expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(expected)
>
> Expected number of calls: 1
> Received number of calls: 0
> ```

Note that changing **push** to **to** doesn't make any difference in the above code either.

The test **does** succeed, however, if I change my  to use a @click callback instead:

```
// Test succeeds with this code
<v-btn id="create-plan-btn" @click="redirect">Create plan</v-btn>

redirect () {
   this.$router.push({ name: 'newPlan', query: { dept: 216001 }});
}
```

Is there a way to modify this test that allows the :to prop to be captured on the  click? I've tried to at least make sure the content of the :to prop is visible in the test, but I only ever get **[object Object]** sent back to me:

```
expect(button.attributes('to').toString()).toEqual({ name: 'newPlan', query: { dept: 216001 }})
```

> Expected: {"name": "newPlan", "query": {"dept": 216001}}
> Received: "[object Object]"

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly certain this has to do with your `emit` and not the fact that you're actually clicking it.

I'd suggest changing your test a bit:

```
it('triggers Vue router call to the new plan page', async () => {
    const button = wrapper.find('#create-plan-btn')
    expect(button.exists()).toBeTruthy()
    expect(mockRouter.push).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(0)
    await button.trigger('click')
    await wrapper.vm.$nextTick() // This could probably be omitted since we're awaiting the click above
    expect(mockRouter.push).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
    expect(mockRouter.push).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ name: 'newPlan', query: { dept: 216001 }})
  })
```

Also, what would be the purpose of testing that the button attributes are what they are? Since you've written them there and they're not dynamic in any way, then they will be that. However, if you really do want to test it, I think the problem is the `toString()` function, and you could instead try JSON stringifying it:

`expect(JSON.stringify(button.attributes('to'))).toEqual({ name: 'newPlan', query: { dept: 216001 }})`

Although it should also be possible to just do:

`expect(button.attributes('to')).toStrictEqual({ name: 'newPlan', query: { dept: 216001 }})`

I don't really know what you mean with your comment that Vuetify buttons would need to use `$emit`, I've always managed to test Vuetify buttons this way.

I'd also suggest one simple change, instead of using ID's for testing, create an attribute `data-testid="router-button"` that you name and find the component with:

`const button = wrapper.find('[data-testid="router-button"]')`

This makes it clear that it's used for testing and nothing else.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer about data-testid.

Comment: I tried to amend the test as you said and I get     

expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(expected)
    Expected number of calls: 1
    Received number of calls: 0

I tried to swap mockRouter.push with mockRouter.to, to no avail.